# how can I highlight ui-grid row on selection/click, which has six pinned columns?

Tags: angularjs, grid, highlight, ui-grid

how can I highlight ui-grid row on selection/click, which has six pinned columns?

I am using UI-grid to render my data. Now I have done some functionality on click of grid row, but for it I want to show highlighted row in pinned column, so How can I fulfill my this requirement here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found simple solution. that is just do following code.

```
row.setSelected(true);
```

Nothing else to do.